# jQuery focus() causes .load() to excecute twice in IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

jQuery focus seems to cause internet explorer 9 to execute twice. This problem doesn't happen in older versions of IE, and doesn't happen in Firefox or Chrome.

I'm having a user enter a code in an input field. On enter or submit the code gets sent through a load to another script (ajax). The code in the input field is removed, and the focus is brought back.

The result of that script is inserted in a div on the same page.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#code').keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                console.log('Code submitted through enter');
                sendcode($('#code').val());
            }
        });

        function sendcode(b){
            console.log('function sendcode used');
            $('#Result').load('scan.php?code=' + b);
            $('#code').val('');
            $('#code').focus();
        };

        $('#Submit').click(function(){
            console.log('Code submitted through click');
            sendcode($('#code').val());
        });
    });
```

However, the focus() seems to be the problem since when I remove it the problem is gone. I have tried placing the focus() in any place of the code but without success. Is there any alternative to focus() that achieves the same or can it somehow be fixed?

```
NETWORK:

URL: /scan.php?code=stackoverflow
URL: /scan.php?code=

CONSOLE: (when hit enter)
Log: Code submitted through click 
Log: function sendcode used 
Log: Code submitted through enter 
Log: function sendcode used
```

You can see the second load doesn't carry the code variable either.

Comment: Add a console log in the click function and see how many times it runs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the console logs and the log. Seems like it gets submitted through click first, and enter second.

Comment: @GillianLo-Wong Can you provide a working demo of the problem?

Comment: @GillianLo-Wong Thats why i `e.preventDefault()` suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Submit` button to a `span` or `div` and style it.

```
<span id="Submit">Submit</span>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hTFqm/2/)

You can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325066/button-click-event-fires-when-pressing-enter-key-in-different-input-no-forms), where adding an attribute `type="button"` to the button element is suggested.

Comment: Cheers, I've used a <button> instead. But the <input type="submit"> caused it to submit twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
    function sendcode(b){
        if(b){
            console.log('function sendcode used');
            $('#Result').load('scan.php?code=' + b);
            $('#code').val('');
            $('#code').focus();
        }
    };
```

Something along those lines should work. Maybe if `b != undefined` or something like that. Just make sure B is there.

Comment: Great and simple solution to 'filter out' the 'bad requests'. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Put the function outside of `doc ready`, try this:

```
function sendcode(b){
  $('#Result').load('scan.php?code=' + b);
  $('#code').val('');
  $('#code').focus();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#code').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            sendcode($('#code').val());
        }
    });

    $('#Submit').click(function(){
        sendcode($('#code').val());
    });
});
```

or try this one:

`.load()` is one of the jquery's `ajax` methods so you have to stop the submissions of form otherwise page gets refreshed.

```
$('#Submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    sendcode($('#code').val());
});
```

Comment: Just because it has an `id` of Submit doesn't mean that it's an actual submit button, or there's a form involved at all.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Jai, but unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work. Also, there is no form involved (sorry for the misconception)

Answer (score 0):

Don't intercept keystrokes unless you really, really mean it.  Certainly don't emulate buttons with spans!  HTML has tags besides `span` and `div` for a reason.

Your problem is arguably an IE bug, but it's what you get for mucking around with builtin behavior that works just fine.  You only need *one* event handler that fires when the *form* is submitted.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function sendcode(b){
        console.log('function sendcode used');
        $('#Result').load('scan.php?code=' + b);
        $('#code').val('');
        $('#code').focus();
    };

    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        sendcode($('#code').val());

    });
});
```

And then, frankly, you can have a more accessible form that doesn't rely on JavaScript, as well as code that's far more reusable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);
        var data = $form.serialize();
        var action = $form.attr('action');
        $('#result').load(action + '?' + data);

        $('#code').val('').focus();
    });
});
```

Now the URL lives on the form's `action` attribute (which is where a form's target URL goes), and the JS will bundle up the form values like the browser would and ajax-submit the form for you.  If the user has JS disabled, the form will submit *normally* and they'll still get a useful result, albeit in a new page.  The code is shorter, URL escaping issues are taken care of for you, and there are fewer hard-coded values.