# jQuery IE 11 clicks buttons on Enter from keyboard

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, click

I have something like an order-page, working with demandware.
I can search for productnames, and I get a list of those.
I click on a product and add it to my cart.
It appears in the cart (on the same page)

There's a jQuery function listening like this:

```
jQuery("button.removeLineItem").click(function() {
    removeLineItem(getButtonVal(jQuery(this)));
});
```

If I press that button, that item is removed from the list again.
My problem is, that this item is being deleted even if I do not actually click the button but click somewhere inside my HTML page and hit ENTER.
Even when the input for the search is focused, it deletes the items.

In Firefox, everything works fine.

I tried to determine keycodes and so on, but without any success.
I tried to use stuff like "blur()" or focus other elements.
I even gave every row an on "onclick()" function but still it's getting executed when I hit enter.

I mean, click() does something like executing everything that is connected to the event.
I also read, that the last element of a form is automatically focused.
But I am not using a form.

ALso, when I deleted all those cart-items by hitting enter; the website tries to execute other buttons.

All problems only in IE 11.
Is there a known bug or anything ?
Anything I could do to prevent this from occuring ?!

Answer (score 1):

Acutally I just found the solution on stackoverflow:

[Button Click event fires when pressing Enter key in different input (no forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325066/button-click-event-fires-when-pressing-enter-key-in-different-input-no-forms)

Just type 
type="button" and IE is happy